# When to prefer anonymous functions in javascript

Tags: javascript

Can somebody explain why anonymous function pass as argument to callback..What will happen if I pass a named function as argument to callback function..

What are the advantages of using anonymous function..
When we should prefer anonymous function..

Comment: It's shorter. Nothing else. You can as well pass named functions, no problems.

Comment: Anonymous functions are used in single case scenarios. If you have something that's going to be repeated 1+ times, probably you'd want to create a  named function & call it wherever you need it.

Comment: anonymous functions are like literal strings or numbers. You can debug better if you named your functions. It is a good practice to pass named functions instead of anonymous. No other difference besides named functions are more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are trying to compare named function expressions to anonymous function expressions:

- Named function expressions will cause memory leaks in old versions of Internet Explorer
- Anonymous functions will produce less helpful reports in a debugger's stacktrace
- Anonymous functions require slightly less typing to create